# How to use https for authentication from EGit to GitHub

Tags: github, egit

I am trying to setup EGit to work with GitHub with https authentication, instead of the default ssh.  (My reason is that I am a teacher, and some of my students do their work from different machines, so it's not convenient to rely on ssh keys stored on disk.)  Has anyone gotten this to work?  When I try doing a "Push to Upstream" using https, I get the unhelpful error message "An internal Exception occured during push: https://espertus@github.com/MillsCollegeMobileAppDev2011/test.git: not authorized".

I am using Eclipse 3.6.2 (Helios) with versions 0.11.3 of Eclipse EGit (Incubation), Eclipse EGit - Source (Incubation), and EGit Mylyn (Incubation).  My Destination Git Repository settings are:

- Location

  - URI: https://espertus@github.com/MillsCollegeMobileAppDev2011/test.git
  - Host: github.com
  - Repository path: /MillsCollegeMobileAppDev2011/test.git
- Connection

  - Protocol: https
  - Port: [unset]
- Authentication

  - User: espertus
  - Password: ........
  - Store in Secure Store: [checked]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need input **your github account password** in:

---

Authentication

User: espertus

Password: **HERE**

Store in Secure Store: [checked]

---

enjoy it! :)

Comment: I did enter my password, but it turned out I mis-entered it.  I suck.

Answer (score 1):

If your password is correct then another problem that can cause this is github's two-factor authentication. Disable it and the push should work.

Answer (score 0):

Like Larry Parks mentioned, you will have issues with eGit access over HTTPS to GitHub when you are using two-factor authentication.  The workaround is to create a "Personal Access Token" and use that instead of your password.

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/